# Vue.js/Axios - Duplicate results in list. Has unique-keys in v-for

Tags: vuejs2, axios, v-for

I have two other uses of v-for in separate components. They also sometimes throw errors. All three v-for invocations are wrapped with v-if/else. Here is the code that produces duplicate key errors & renders data twice:

**AccountDashboard.vue**

```
<tbody>
  <tr v-if="!residents.length" class="table-info">
    <td class="text-center">
      <p>
        No residents on record. 
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <template v-else>
    <tr is="AccountResidentList"
      v-for="resident in residents"
      v-bind:key="'resident-list-' + resident.id"
      v-bind:first_name="resident.first_name"
      v-bind:last_name="resident.last_name"
      v-bind:dob="resident.dob | date_formatted"
      >
    </tr>
  </template>
</tbody>
```

Note the unique id attempt in the binding of key.

Here is a look at the child component

**ProviderAccountList.vue**

```
<template>
  <tr class="AccountResidentList">
    <td>
      {{ this.$attrs.id }}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{ this.$attrs.first_name }} {{ this.$attrs.last_name }}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{ this.$attrs.dob }}
    </td>
    <td>
      <button @click="toResidentProfile({account_id, id})" class="btn btn-sm btn-purple btn-with-icon">
        <div class="ht-25">
         <span class="icon wd-25"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></span>
         <span class="pd-x-10">view</span>
       </div>
      </button>
    </td>
    <!--TODO: Add view profile button-->
  </tr>
</template>

 <script>
 import Axios from "axios";
 import router from "../../router";
 import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
 import moment from "moment";

 export default {
  name: "AccountResidentList",
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters['Resident', {
      resident: 'getResident'
    }]
  },
  filters: {
    date_formatted: (date) => {
      return moment(date).format('MMMM Do, YYYY');
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toResidentProfile(account_id, resident_id) {
      router.push(`/accounts/${account_id}/residents/${resident_id}`)
    }
  },
};
 </script>
 <style scoped></style>
```

My Axios call looks like:

**Account.js** *(a namespaced vuex-module)*

```
  async retrieveAccount(context, account_id) {
      // Axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + window.$cookies.get('jwt')
      let response
      let valid_id = window.$cookies.get('valid_id');
      response = await Axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/providers/${valid_id}/accounts/${account_id}`, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + window.$cookies.get('jwt') } })
      .then((response) => {
        let account = response.data.locals.account;
        let account_address = response.data.locals.account_address;
        let residents = response.data.locals.residents;
        // set Account
        context.dispatch('Account/setId', account.id, {root: true});
        context.dispatch('Account/setProviderId', account.provider_id, {root: true});
        .
        .
        .

        // set AccountAddress
        // !Array.isArray(array) || !array.length
        if (account.address) {
          context.dispatch('Account/setAddressId', account_address.id, {root: true});
          context.dispatch('Address/setId', account_address.id, {root: true});
        .
        .
        . 

        // set AccountResidents
        // !Array.isArray(array) || !array.length
        residents.forEach(resident => {
          if (resident) {
            // Add object to parent's list
            context.dispatch('Account/setResidents', resident, {root: true});         // Set attr values for object
            context.dispatch('Resident/setId', resident.id, {root: true});
            .
            .
            .
            (remaining attrs removed for brevity)
          }
        })

        router.push(`/providers/${account.provider_id}/accounts/${account_id}`);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
```

Note: the Account action #setResidents simply calls the mutator that adds one resident to a list total.

`i.e state.list.push(resident)`

I logged the response to the console and can confirm that the data isn't being sent twice (or more) from my Axios call.

[image: console.log results]

I have reviewed & attempted the following to no avail:

- https://alligator.io/vuejs/iterating-v-for/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/7n3zi4/vue_warn_duplicate_keys_detected_vfor_with/
- https://github.com/hejianxian/vddl/issues/23
- https://github.com/hejianxian/vddl#warning
- https://medium.com/@chiatsai/vue-js-common-issue-duplicate-keys-stops-components-rendering-df415f31838e

Finally, It should be mentioned that I have tried variations of using/not using `template` to wrap the list, including/not including the for loop in the `template`, etc..

Did not anticipate it would be this bothersome to iterate a collection.

Am I overlooking something obvious?

**Update: What worked for me**

I needed access to the resident.id also the id declared in the paren seems like an index. So here is a look at what removed the duplicate render errors and allow me access to the resident's id even after fixing the duplicate keys error:

```
<template v-else>
  <tr is="AccountResidentList"
    v-for="(resident, id) in residents"
    v-bind:key="id"
    v-bind:id="resident.id"
    v-bind:first_name="resident.first_name"
    v-bind:last_name="resident.last_name"
    v-bind:dob="resident.dob | date_formatted"
  >
  </tr>
</template>
```

Thanks again @Billal Begueradj for the assist!

Comment: Try: `v-for="(resident, id) in residents"
      :key="'id"`

Comment: @Billal Begueradj +1 for the quick response! This works for all of my iterations. If you place this as an answer I will accept. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For me, I suspect that in `residents` there are entries which have the same id. So we have to find out a way to overcome this issue. We can give it an efficient try as follows:

```
<tr 
  is="AccountResidentList"
  v-for="(resident, id) in residents"
  :key="id"
  // rest of your code
```

Comment: My duplicate keys error is gone but to your point of entries with the same id, my list is now being rendered twice. The illustration (image of console.log) shows unique id's for each resident present. Is there a reason why that would change when pinging my server?

Comment: With the duplicate keys error gone. My list was duplicating until I allowed my bound key to act as id. Prior to fixing the double render, I was also binding the id, causing the dups. Removing this and using the key instead returns the desired results.

Comment: Hard to follow the code in **Account.js**,  especially without a testable code that I can try. However,  try: 1. In **AccountDashboard.vue** replace  `is="AccountResidentList"` by `class="AccountResidentList"`. 2. **ProviderAccountList.vue**, remove `  <tr class="AccountResidentList">` and `</tr>` @sirramongabriel You can un-accept my answer if it it does not help, so that hopefully someone else could throw a look at your code deeper